# MongoDb $near and query

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, 2dsphere

I have a collection of documents in structure as below

```
{ _id: ObjectId("54723e44ec73a702fc979fc9"), 
    Start: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -0.15261409999993703, 51.4428311 ] }, 
    End: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -0.1258020000000215, 51.44695 ] } 
}
```

I am running the following query to try and find documents where the start is 2000 units from a point and the end is 1 unit from a point.

```
"Start" : 
     { "$near" : 
          { "$geometry" : 
             { "type" : "Point", 
                   "coordinates" : [-0.12580200000002151, 51.44695]
              }
          },
      "$maxDistance" : 2000.0 
 }, 
 "End" : 
    { "$near" : 
         { "$geometry" : 
             { "type" : "Point", 
                    "coordinates" : [-0.12580200000002151, 51.44695]
             }
         },
      "$maxDistance" : 1.0 
    }
```

When I run the query it always returns the documents as if it is doing an or.  So where start is x units from a point OR end is x units from a point.  So if I run it over the following two documents it returns both where I would only expect the first to be returned.

```
{ _id: ObjectId("54723e44ec73a702fc979fc9"), 
  Start: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -0.15261409999993703, 51.4428311 ] }, 
  End: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -0.1258020000000215, 51.44695 ] }
}
{ _id: ObjectId("54724f0cec73a70c383a27d4"), 
  Start: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -0.15261409999993703, 51.4428311 ] }, 
  End: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -0.09553900000003068, 51.427025 ] } 
}
```

I am sure I should be able to do this as in

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/50984169045/new-geo-features-in-mongodb-2-4

"Additionally, we can have multiple 2dsphere indexes in the same compound index. This allows queries like: “Find routes with a start location within 50 miles from JFK, and an end location within 100 miles of YYC”."

For clarrification.  The query shown above is supposed to be doing and AND query on START location $near point AND END location $near point.  But what it actually appears to be doing is START location $near point OR END location $near point.

How do I do and AND query on two $near queries in a single document?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: Can you please indent your JSON. It is very hard to follow a query when you have to scroll across the page.